# Speed up counting query in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm workig with `Django2.1` + `python3.5` + `mysql5.7`

Below are some detail infos:

db table

```py
# models
class FbAccountSpendCapHandle(BaseModel):
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle'
```

```sql
# SQL
CREATE TABLE `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `account_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `account_status` smallint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `submitter` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `submit_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_delete` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `urgent` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_violation` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `condition` (`is_delete`,`submit_time`,`submitter`,`status`,`urgent`,`type`,`is_violation`,`account_status`,`apply_id`,`account_name`(191),`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

After doing some condition query, I want to count total numbers of all query data. Query detail as below:

```py
tem_queryset = FbAccountSpendCapHandle.objects.filter(...)
print(tem_queryset.query)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle` 
WHERE (`ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`is_delete` = 0 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` BETWEEN "1970-01-01 00:00:00" AND "2021-03-27 16:04:31" 
AND `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submitter` IN ("a", "b", "c")) 
ORDER BY `ka_fb_account_spend_cap_handle`.`submit_time` DESC
```

Then I want to get the count of filtered data

```py
c = tem_queryset.count()
```

But the query cost about `2s` for there being more than `200k` queried data.

How can I get the count more effectively?

Comment: Why do you need `between` if lower boundary is actually Unix epoch start time? `between` is a shortcut to `field >= lowe bound AND field < higher bound`, so replacing it with only `<` will give's you a bit more speed

Comment: @Charnel I take your suggestion and speed up my query. But the `count` still take about `1.5s`, any advise to do more  optimiz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is to remove ordering which is a very costly operation:

```
c = tem_queryset.order_by().count()
```

This will remove the ordering you can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Also you can add `db_index=True` for `submit_time`

Comment: It seems not working to add just `order_by()` in my situation

Comment: Besides I need use `paginator` so it supposed to be a `ordered_queryset`. Can u give me some advise?

Comment: Yes but the count do not change even if you remove the ordering. Ordering is only needed in your main query in the count query you do not need ordering